# Hvaing trouble generating new random operator

Tags: java, switch-statement, operator-keyword

Im trying to generate a random operator for every line;

my code for generating a random operator is;

```
Random operatorChoice = new Random();
int operator = operatorChoice.nextInt(3);

 int b = (0);
 int c = (0);
```

String operatorSwitch;

```
    switch (operator){// generates random operators

        case 0: operatorSwitch= "+";
         
            c = (int) (firstNumbereasy+secondNumbereasy);
            break;
        case 1: operatorSwitch= "-";
            c = (int) (firstNumbereasy-secondNumbereasy);
            break;
        case 2: operatorSwitch= "*";
            c = (int) (firstNumbereasy*secondNumbereasy);
            break;
        case 3: operatorSwitch= "/";
            c = (int) (firstNumbereasy/secondNumbereasy);
            
       default: operatorSwitch = "";
               
      
    }
```

Trying to print two different random operators:

```
> System.out.println("Question 1, what is " + firstNumbereasy +operatorSwitch+ secondNumbereasy );
             b= scanner.nextInt();
              
             
             firstNumbereasy = randN.nextInt(9)+2; 
             secondNumbereasy= randN.nextInt(firstNumbereasy - 1); 

             System.out.println("Question 2, what is " + firstNumbereasy + operatorSwitch + secondNumbereasy); 
            b = scanner.nextInt();`
```

but the same operator is being generated for both question 1 and 2

Comment: Note that nextInt(3) will never return 3. See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)): *Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)*. And you don't change `operatorswitch` between the questions so I'm not sure why you expect it to change...

Comment: what am i supposed to change it to to generate another random operator?

Comment: You could write a `getRandomOperator` method that returns a random operatorSwitch - and in the last piece of code, you need to write `String operatorSwitch = getRandomOperator();` before each question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that nextInt(3) will never return 3. See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)):

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive).

Separately, you don't change `operatorswitch` between the questions so its value won't change.

One solution would be to write a `getRandomOperator()` method that returns a random `operatorSwitch` - and in the last piece of code, you can then call that method before each question.